# Ribbon - Maximized MDI child window doesn't occupy the entire main window if the Ribbon controls on these windows are merged

Tags: delphi, layout, devexpress, delphi-xe3

When I create a new project I select the "DevExpress 2010 application" then I make the main form MDIForm and the second form MDIChild and then I added dxRibbon controls to both forms but when I create the second form and try to maximize it it produces this:
[image]

If there is no dxribbon control in the second form everything works OK, so I guess it has something to do with the Ribbon control itself any ideas?

The merging isn't the problem the main problem is that when you maximize the unit4 it doesn't fill the parent as in the picture.

Source Code (updated sharing link 2022): [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RiKAQqceUDeXBERU53clVZMVk/view?usp=drivesdk&resourcekey=0-ZeHAc2UyM274EDoR4LALqg)

Comment: what is your goal? I think it is normal if you make MDIChild that it maximize in parent?

Comment: yes its normal but whats not normal that it doesn't fill the parent it only fills it partially and then if you maximize the parent it fills the parent all the way.

Comment: ask it on DevExpress forum - you paid them money to help with debugging your application. Usually few days later they just send your sample application back with fixes made

Comment: I wonder if DevEx ribbons are wrappers around Microsoft Ribbon Controls or are DevEx's own tabula rasa design. Microsoft's trend is to deprecate MDI in favor of SDI and to deprecate toolbars in favor of ribbons. I would not be surprised if Microsoft Ribbons just would not support MDI mode // Which of your two ribbons is visible on the screenshot? // Also I wonder which controls are allowed in MDIOwner form at all, except for menu and statusbar. There is an invisible MDI Controller window inside MDI Owner, that exactly serves as a maximum viewport for children. Maybe non-empty Owner confuses it

Comment: i would ask on DevEx but my subscription ended thus i don't have support anymore, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've downloaded your example and I've set a group in the ribbon of unit4. When I maximaze unit4, the group is merged in the parent (unit 2). So what is just the problem.

Comment: the merging isn't the problem the main problem is that when you maximize the unit4 it doesn't fill the parent as in the picture, if in your version of devexpress does fill the parent please post the version and steps taken, thank you.

Comment: @Arioch'The: The DevEx ribbons are DevEx's own code but closely modeled after Microsoft's rules.

Comment: your subscription end means you cannot download newer software, but you can ask on forum about already owned. Maybe no one would answer you, but maybe they will, why not just try?

Comment: I have no subscription but still always get an answer from DevEx.

Comment: well i trust this site more than them, and am still waiting for an answer :) so anyone?

Comment: Ok so i asked devexpress and the reproduced the behaviour will post the sollution when i get an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like it was a bug, still awaiting the details how to apply to older versions of DevExpress VCL the bug is confirmed and reproduced you can follow the details [-->here--<](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q566225)

i will post the answer here also when i get it :) hope this helps some of you.

**EDIT:**

Response from DevExpress Developers:

> There is no way to get the hotfix for VCL 12.1.6; this version is too
>   old. Moreover, currently there are so many changes in the
>   dxMessages.pas and dxBar.pas units (comparing to the released VCL
>   13.2.2 build) that it is even impossible to get the hotfix for VCL 13.2.2. Fortunately, we are finishing VCL 13.2.3 right now and this fix will be included there.

Bug fixed in:

> v2013 vol 2.3 : Hotfix is not available, please wait for the next
>   official update